# how to host a custom control in custom cell in DataGridView?

Tags: .net

I have a custom control that I had created I need to host it in the cell of DataGridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx)

Implement `IDataGridViewEditingControl` in your control and create a custom DGV column by extending `DataGridViewColumn` and a custom DGV cell by extending `DataGridViewCell`.

The linked MSDN article has an excellent example.